# How to add condition to left join on existing the row in another table

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT
   p.id,
   COUNT(a.id) accounts,
   sum(case when a.state = '0' then 1 else 0 end) active_accounts
FROM Person p
  LEFT JOIN Account a
  ON a.person_id = p.id ADN 
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

How can I add condition on account have an valid `bank_name` by cheking the `bank` table ON `account.bank_name = bank.name` to both `accounts` and `active_accounts` values?

this is db scheme:

```
Person (
  id
)

Account (
  id
  person_id
  state -- 0 - active, 1 - closed
  bank_name
)

Bank (
  id,
  name
)
```

If `Account` have incorrect `bank_name` (there are no such row in `Bank` table) it shouldn't be counted.

Comment: what is `a1.state`?  pls add more information about the schemas or prepare a sqlfiddle with data to operate on

Comment: You have referenced a table or subquery by the alias `A1` - what is that? Please provide the complete working query. is `A1` just `A` perhaps?

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yes, this is misspelling. Should be `A`

Comment: What your database server ?

Comment: Since you're specifying `WHERE p.id = 1`, there is no need for the `GROUP BY p.id`.

Comment: Why would accounts have invalid `bank_name`s?

Comment: Hes not ForeignKeying them, thats why. Bad DDL design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somethings like this, add left join to bank table and a where clause to check if name is not null :

```
SELECT
   p.id,
   COUNT(a.id) accounts,
   sum(case when a.state = '0' then 1 else 0 end) active_accounts
FROM Person p
  LEFT JOIN Account a ON
      a.person_id = p.id
  LEFT JOIN bank b ON
      a.bank_name = b.name
WHERE p.id = 1 and
    b.name is not null
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: a1 was in initial question

Comment: @Indent You also have an extraneous "ADN" at the end of the `Account` join. Given the `LEFT JOIN Accounts`, it seems that the `b.name IS NOT NULL` condition will strip out records where the Person did not have an account. If that's what's needed, the `LEFT JOIN`s should be `INNER JOIN`s

Comment: @Patrick Artner : I have read your remark and edit my answer. the question was not in relation with `a1` error. Please remote your downvote. thanks

Comment: @Indent sure, but you only fixed one of the issues mentioned by @PatrickArtner, and I think the conditions in your `WHERE` clause need to be adjusted.

Comment: @both : OK. think ADN was a previous AND ;-)

Answer (score 1):

see  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b43b3/3

```
 SELECT
   p.id,
   COUNT(a.id) accounts,
   sum(case when a.state = '0' then 1 else 0 end) active_accounts
FROM Person p
  LEFT JOIN Account a ON a.person_id = p.id   
  INNER JOIN Bank on a.bank_name = Bank.name 

WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

A saner ddl would be smth like this with use of foreign keys

```
create table person (
  id int unique not null
);

create table bank (
  id int unique not null,
  name nvarchar(10) 
);

create table account ( 
  id int unique not null, 
  person_id int,
  state bit, 
  bank_id int,
  FOREIGN KEY (bank_id) REFERENCES bank(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id)
); 

Insert into person values (1), (2); 
insert into bank VALUES (1, "B1"),(2, "B2");
insert into account values (1,1,1,1), (2,1,0,1),(3,1,1,1),(4,2,1,1);
```

This kind of DDL will allow you to have `accounts` without banks (`bank_id` == null) or `accounts` with valid `bank_ids` - the DB takes care of it for you - no need for the unsecure join on ncharchar()s - which might go wrong if you commit some trailing/leading spaces

Comment: The SELECT statement in your answer will not strip out results with Accounts with invalid bank names.

Comment: If the Bank join is an INNER JOIN then the Account join may as well be too. It's not 100% clear to me what the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with CTE (if your Database support it) :

```
with account_valid as (
    select
        a.*
    from
        Account a 
        inner join bank b on
            a.bank_name = b.name
)
select
    p.id,
    count(a.id) accounts,
    sum(case when a.state = '0' then 1 else 0 end) active_accounts
from
    Person p
    left join account_valid a ON
      a.person_id = p.id ADN   
where
    p.id = 1 -- condition just for test
group by
    p.id
```

or with nested query :

```
select
    p.id,
    count(a.id) accounts,
    sum(case when a.state = '0' then 1 else 0 end) active_accounts
from
    Person p
    left join (
        select
            a.*
        from
            Account a 
            inner join bank b on
                a.bank_name = b.name
    ) account_valid a ON
      a.person_id = p.id ADN   
where
    p.id = 1 -- condition just for test
group by
    p.id
```